# Can not connect to redis-stack-server from node docker container (locally)

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, redis-stack-server

When I run docker container that hass node express app.js it can not connect to redis-stack-server running locally.

However, if I do it without docker container everything works fine.

I ran esbuild to generate one app.js file but it is express ts app. It connects to redis-stack-server.
Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18

ENV REDIS_URL="redis://localhost:6379"
ENV NODE_PORT=3000

COPY app.js .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

And here is how I set up redis client in node app:

```
export const redisC = async () => {
    const client : RedisClientType = createClient();
    client.on('error', (err) => console.error('Redis Client Error', err));
    await client.connect();
    return client;
}

export let redisClient : RedisClientType;
redisC().then((response) => {
    redisClient = response
}).catch(error => console.error(error))
```

I do run locally:

```
redis-stack-server
```

I build docker container:

```
docker build . -t my-app
```

Then I run:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 my-app
```

However i face the following issue when I run docker container:

```
Redis Client Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379
}
```

If I run app.js locally not with docker then everything works.

```
Express listening on port 3000
```

And no errors regarding redis connection.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you tried running “docker run -p 6379:3000 my-app”? Seams like you didn’t change redis default port (in the URL)

Comment: There's a pretty good SO post on how the `localhost` works for inside containers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/6336357

Comment: @RickRackow that actually helped! Thank you so much. If i change redis client to: const client : RedisClientType = createClient({
        url: "redis://host.docker.internal:6379",
    }); it did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

In Docker each container runs in isolation, so `localhost` means different things. `localhost` on your machine is not the same as `localhost` in the express container.

Redis is running on `127.0.0.1:6379` on your machine, but not on that address inside the express container. That's why running express outside of a container works fine.

You probably want [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for this.

```
services:
  express:
    ...
    environment:
      REDIS_URL: redis:6379
    ports:
      - 3000:3000 // <- forwards traffic from port 3000 on your machine to port 3000 in container

  redis:
    ...
    ports:
      - 6379:6379 // <- same as above
```

The crucial part is `REDIS_URL: redis:6379` in the express service, which tells the express container where redis can be contacted, which in Docker compose is using the service name.

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLUTION]
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) article really helped! To make it work locally we need to change redis URL to:

```
url: "redis://host.docker.internal:6379"
```

So my full redis client config:

```
export const redisC = async () => {
    const client : RedisClientType = createClient({
        url: "redis://host.docker.internal:6379",
    });
    client.on('error', (err) => console.error('Redis Client Error', err));
    await client.connect();
    return client;
}
```

Thanks a lot everyone for participation! I really much appreciate the help!